# How to select all fields from a single box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwvYRN)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="box1">
  <fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" class="select-all">
  <label>Select All </label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Checkbox1</label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Checkbox3 </label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Checkbox3 </label>
  </fieldset>

</div>

<div class="box2">
  <fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" class="select-all">
  <label>Select All </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Checkbox4 </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Checkbox5 </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Checkbox6 </label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.box1{
  background:#d9d9d9;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.box2{
  background:#ccc;
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$('.select-all').click(function(event) {
         if(this.checked) {
             // Iterate each checkbox
             $(':checkbox').each(function() {
                 this.checked = true;
             });
         }else{
             $(':checkbox').each(function() {
                 this.checked = false;
             });
         }
     });
```

What I want to do is that when the button "select-all" is checked, select all fields in a box.

At this time, set all inputs ... and I wish only the current box.

How can I change my function so that it works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.closest()` to find the parent div, then use `.find()` method to get the checkboxes inside it,

```
$('.select-all').click(function(event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    // Iterate each checkbox
    $(this).closest("div").find(':checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  } else {
    $(this).closest("div").find(':checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwvYEv)

You can reduce your code like this also,

```
$('.select-all').click(function(event) {
  var obj=this;
  var parent = $(this).closest("div[class^=box]");
  parent.find(':checkbox').each(function() {
    this.checked = obj.checked;
  });
});
```

As A.Wolf suggested, you can use like this too,

```
 $('.select-all').change(function(event) {
  $(this).closest('div[class^=box]').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Ya but you could refactorize it a little: `$('.select-all').change(function(event) {
 $(this).closest('div[class^=box]').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);    
 });` and use instead change event but doesn't really matter here

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for the suggestion, I have edited the code.

Comment: @A.Wolff didnt know that prop will apply for all the elements. I thought it will apply for the first element only.

Comment: Ya, like most jQuery setter methods and unlike getter ones.